# mysql fulltext query difference

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have followed [this tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-natural-language-search.aspx) for mysql fulltext search.

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `textrow` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `textrow` (`textrow`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `textrow`) VALUES
(1, 'Agajan Torayev'),
(2, 'torayeff');

ALTER TABLE test ADD FULLTEXT(textrow);
```

What is the difference between these queries (one gives zero results):

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test WHERE MATCH(textrow) AGAINST('agajan');
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

AND

```
mysql> SELECT *, MATCH(textrow) AGAINST('agajan') FROM test;
+----+----------------+----------------------------------+
| id | textrow        | MATCH(textrow) AGAINST('agajan') |
+----+----------------+----------------------------------+
|  1 | Agajan Torayev |                                0 |
|  2 | torayeff       |                                0 |
+----+----------------+----------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that in the 1st query you filter your result with the `match`ing data and with the 2nd query you output all records and add a column to show what `match`ing would result.

You don't get a result though because

> A natural language search interprets the search string as a phrase in natural human language (a phrase in free text). [...] In addition, **words that are present in 50% or more of the rows are considered common and do not match**.

[Taken from MySQL Full-Text Search Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: But then why the first query gives 0 results, it should match first insertion????

Comment: full text match only returns a result if the searched word is in less than 50% of the records. Otherwise it is ignored as a common word.